# Fat Jar Export: Could not find class-path entry for 'logging/bin/default'

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, logging

I am facing an issue while creating a Fat Jar using create runnable JAR option in Eclipse. Error is: Fat Jar Export: Could not find class-path entry for 'logging/bin/default'. I know this has been mentioned by some other users also, but I did not get relevant answer to my error so I am putting my question here. My code is in Java, its spring boot based and build tool used is Gradle. Its a Java consume code, simple one but am not getting why Fat Jar creation always gives error now. Below is the my build.gradle contents:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
repositories {
jcenter()
mavenCentral()
}
jar {
baseName = 'logging'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
dependencies {
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25'
compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.8.2'
compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.8.2'
compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.8.2'
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.0.1'
}
```

Please provide some suggestion on this.

Comment: any luck regarding this issue?